# Creating a dynamic Form Django

Tags: python, django, forms

Consider these Django models:

```
class MonitorSession(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    contact_motive = models.ForeignKey(ContactMotive)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    protocole_number = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    strong_points = models.TextField(blank=True)
    points_to_improve = models.TextField(blank=True)
    action_plan = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s, %s" % (self.customer_number, self.protocole_number)

class EvaluationCategory(models.Model):
    cel = models.ForeignKey(Cel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    max_points = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s: %s" % (self.cel, self.category)


class EvaluationItem(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(EvaluationCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s: %s" % (self.category, self.item)

class EvaluationScore(models.Model):
    monitor_session = models.ForeignKey(MonitorSession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(EvaluationItem, )
    score = models.ForeignKey(PossibleScore, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s: %s" % (self.item, self.score)
```

Now I need to create a form to with these all the fields from the MonitorSession class.

After those fields I would need to create additional form fields which are dynamic, and would be returning from this query:

```
fields = EvaluationItem.objects.all().order_by(EvaluationCategory__category)
```

As you can Imagine the number of fields is not known and is dynamic.

Is there an automated way in Django to get this done? Ar will I have to create the form manually and for the Item fields a loop? I have been trying to get this done with Formsets but I do not see how formsets could help me in this.

Comment: I was working through a similar problem recently. This blog post was instrumental to my success https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

Comment: Hi, this did pat of the Job!

Comment: I cannot get this to work. The code from the jacobian in my opinion is not referenced enough. No models. I am completely in the dark ;(

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion is giving me part of the solution: This would be the code of my Form:

```
class MonitorSessionForm(forms.Form):
    agent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Agent.objects.all())
    date = forms.DateField()
    contact_motive =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ContactMotive.objects.all())
    customer_number = forms.CharField(max_length=65)
    protocole_number = forms.CharField(max_length=65)
    strong_points = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    points_to_improve = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    action_plan = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
        super(MonitorSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for i, item in enumerate(extra):
        self.fields['custum_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label=item)
```

My template code:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<h2>Fazer Monitoria</h2>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form method="post" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
             {% bootstrap_form form %}
         <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salvar Monitoria" class="btn btn-primary">
     </form>
     <br><br> 
 </div>
```

And my View code:

```
@login_required()
def add_monitorsession(request):
     items = EvaluationItem.objects.all()
     if request.method == 'POST':
     form = MonitorSessionForm(request.POST, extra=items)
     if form.is_valid():
        print u'Tudo ok!'
else:
     form = MonitorSessionForm
return render_to_response('add_monitorsession.html', {'form': form})
```

Trying to render this is giving me a key error:

```
 KeyError at /addmonitorsession/
 'extra'
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/addmonitorsession/
 Django Version:    1.9.6
 Exception Type:    KeyError
 Exception Value:   
 'extra'
 Exception Location:         ..../monitoria_altocontato/main/forms/monitor_session.py in __init__, line 19
```

pointing out to the next line of the form

```
        extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
```

Any one an idea?